# How to catch the scroll event in gwt on the text area widget

Tags: gwt

A scroll bar gets added to a  read only text area in gwt when the text overflows. 
When I click on the scroll bar down arrow and for example my text area has 3 lines of text in it!(So the three lines are as follows:
Text Area 3 (top)
Text Area 2
Text Area 1)

[Text Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1y0C.png).

When I scroll down using the down arrow of the scroll bar I can see text 3 and directly it scrolls to Text 1 skipping Text 2.How should I control the height of the text which is displayed in the text area when the scroll bar is scrolled down. 
While scrolling up one can see all the three text lines in order.
The browser used for this is google chrome. It works proparely in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will solve your problelm

[How to scroll a GWT TextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409316/how-to-scroll-a-gwt-textarea)

just use scroll api's and you are good to go

Comment: This link is to set the scroll bar to the cursor position. However, my text area is read only. The only way I can scroll up and down is by using the vertical scroll bar. If I click on the down button on the scroll bar it skips a line and goes to the next one. Therefore when the screen is displaying Text3 and I click on the down scroll button it skips text 2 and displays text1.